# Sublime Text doesn't hide on startup

Tags: macos, login, startup, login-items, sublimetext

I added Sublime Text to my Login Items, so that it starts up automatically when I start up my Mac. However, even though I have the Hide box checked already, the app still does not hide on startup.

Is there anything else I can try to get it to hide on startup?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding Sublime Text to your login items, create an applescript like the one below and add it.

```
tell application "Sublime Text" to run
delay 0.5
tell application "Finder"
    set visible of process "Sublime Text" to false
end tell
```

Comment: Okay I'll try that. I'm guessing it runs Sublime Text immediately, then delays for half a second, then hides it. So wouldn't that make it look like ST is "flashing", though? Or, is there a known problem with ST where it will refuse to hide if the hide command is given immediately after the open command?

Comment: The problem is that can be a delay until the app is visible, so, if you `set visible to false` when it's not visible, it won't work. Maybe you have to adjust to delay value, putting the right value, you won't be able to see the Sublime Text window.